# San Francisco planter

Tags: identification, succulents

I saw this plant in several San Francisco planters. Can someone please tell me what it is? I'd like to try growing it.

[image: succulent to be identified]

Answer (score 2):

This is [Echeveria elegans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echeveria_elegans) or Mexican snowball or white Mexican rose. As you can tell from an images search this is a highly variable plant in leaf shape from pointed to blunt to wavy, but they share the silvery colour and the arching pink flowers with yellow tips. Good for dry, hot areas and rock gardens.